# javascirpt could not found when use bind

Tags: javascript, node.js

I had two arrays for storing function/method.
when I did not use bind , I could find the index in the array.
but when I used bind , it could not be found.

```
   function print(){}

    var functionArray1 = new Array();
    functionArray1.push(print);
    console.log(functionArray1.indexOf(print));

    var functionArray2 = new Array();
    functionArray2.push(print.bind(this));
    console.log(functionArray2.indexOf(print.bind(this)));
```

**result**:
0
-1

Comment: `bind()` creates a new function, so your two instances of `print.bind(this)` don't refer to the same function object.

Comment: `.bind()` returns a new function that wraps the original function and thus is not equal to the original function. `.indexOf(print)` doesn't find it because `print.bind() !== print`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind` creates a *new* function. `indexOf` will only return zero or a positive index if the passed object *exactly matches* one of the items in the array - so, for example, for objects, functions, and primitives, they must be `===` for the `indexOf` test to pass.

```js
function print() {}
const boundPrint = print.bind(this);
console.log(boundPrint === print);
```

Otherwise, if the passed object is not `===` to any elements in the array, `-1` will be returned by `indexOf`. This is expected behavior.

Comment: thank for your reply. In that case how could I know if the array include the function?

Comment: You can't, not with such a simple data structure. In general, if you have function `a` and a function `b` which was created via `a.bind`, I don't think it's possible to tell afterwards whether they stem from the same underlying function.

Answer (score 0):

> when I used bind , it could not be found

Every time you use `.bind()`, it returns a new function. Since you called it twice, 2 new functions got created, and one isn't the same as the other (they point to different memory addresses).

```js
function print() {}

const printA = print.bind(this) // this generates a function at a certain memory address
const printB = print.bind(this) // this generates another function at another memory address

console.log("is printA == printB ?", printA == printB) // false

const printC = printA          // this declares a new constant that points to an existing address
console.log("is printC == printA ?", printC == printA) // true
```

Hope this helps clarify. Cheers,